# Can only edit fist list item in a list Sharepoint 2010/13

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath

I have three LISTS A, B, and C.

Each list that was created in SharePoint 2010 and migrated to SharePoint 2013. Up until two days ago, there were not any issues with viewing and editing any list items.  Currently I have multiple items in LIST B and can only view /edit only the first item in the list

LIST A is the original list and is contents are copied/deleted from LIST A and put into LIST B and the same for LIST B to LIST C

I had to update the multi-line text fields to plain text because they would not expand.

There were seven form views in each for each list using InfoPath 2010. Currently still using IP 2010.

LIST A uses only View 1 and 2 of the seven views.
LIST B uses only View 2, 3, and 4 of the seven views. 
LIST C uses only View 2, 4, 5, 6 and 7 of the seven views.

I wanted remove unnecessary forms in each list.  I removed the views from each list and that is when I noticed the problem in LIST B.

Has anyone encountered this?  Looking for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the previous response.  I tried most of the suggested items that I had access to and many others without success.  I did find the answer today.  It turns out that on form load in infopath that there was a query of the main data connection that was preventing anyone (including admins) from viewing any other item than the first item in the list. Once that query was removed it returned to normal

Answer (score 0):

1. Modify the current list view to check whether there is a filter or Item limit specified for this view.
2. Check the permissions on the items to see if the user has permissions to view and edit them.
3. Add `?contents=1` at the end of the URL of the page to open Web Part Page Maintenance page, remove the web parts contain the script and check if it works.
4. Check the ULS log.